# Meteor highchart in modal

Tags: meteor, highcharts, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to show a chart inside of a modal.

I am using Meteor with the maazalik:highcharts package. Initially, when the modal appears the chart is outside of the modal. As soon as I resize the window, the chart appears correctly inside the modal.

A button click event triggers:

```
$('#accountsDetailsModal').modal('show');
```

My modal sits in a template:

```
  <template name="AccountsGraph">  
   <div id="accountsDetailsModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close on-close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Accounts Details</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="container" style="width:100%;margin: 0 auto">
                       {{> highchartsHelper chartId="accountsDetails" chartWidth="100%" charHeight="100%" chartObject=accountsGraph}} 
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default on-close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</template>
```

[image: Screenshot]

EDIT: I replaced my click event handler and it worked.

```
 $('#accountsDetailsModal').modal('show');
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("reflow");
        $("#accountsDetails").highcharts().reflow();
    },200);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add to your config object:

```
func: function(chart) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                chart.reflow();
            }, 0);
        }
```